# Get Linux top command result

Tags: linux, command

I want to get top command result of a specific process and then save it in a file.
I tried the following command:

```
top | grep "qemu" > file
```

but this doesn't work. 
How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-b` and `-n` command line options:

```
top -bn1 | grep qemu > file
```

From `man top`:

> **-b**  :Batch-mode operation
>               Starts  top  in 'Batch' mode, which could be useful for sending output from top to other programs or to a file.
>               In this mode, top will not accept input and runs until the iterations limit  you've  set  with  the  '-n'  com‐
>               mand-line option or until killed.
>
> **-n**  :Number-of-iterations limit as:  -n number
>               Specifies the maximum number of iterations, or frames, top should produce before ending.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
top -b -p `pgrep -d, -f qemu` > top-output.txt
```

-b : Batch mode operation
            Starts top in "Batch mode", which could be useful for sending out-
            put from top to other programs or to a file.  In  this  mode,  top
            will  not  accept input and runs until the iterations limit youâve
            set with the â-nâ command-line option or until killed.